# How to define width and height of the views in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I implement the android game through drawable canvas and i want the banner ad in my game play. but right now its shows banner but unable to see my whole game play i see only white screen. How to solve this problem?

[This is my game play which is made up of drawable canvas in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDiMG.png)

[after changing in this code my game play shows white screen and its show only banner ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IMXC.png)

GameActivity.java

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //GameView gView = new GameView(this);
        GameView gView = new GameView(this);
        gView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-0664573200302260/332653322424");
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

//Additionally to adjust the position to Bottom
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);



// Create a banner ad
        mAdView = new AdView(this);
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

// Create an ad request.
        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();


// Optionally populate the ad request builder.
        adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

// Add the AdView to the view hierarchy.
        layout.addView(mAdView);

// Start loading the ad.
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

        setContentView(layout);


    }
}
```

Comment: The `LinearLayout` you add is probably taking up all the screen space

Comment: this activity directly connected to my game play

Comment: you forgot to add game view in main layout. **layout.addView(gView);**

Comment: according to you @NiranjPatel i add the layout.addView(gView); but my banner ads show in top not in bottom

Comment: you can add game view in ads in xml

Comment: i add the ads in xml but still its showing on the top

Answer (score 0):

```js
Your_View.getLayoutParams().height  = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.Whatever_Height);

Your_View.getLayoutParams().width  = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.Whatever_Height);
```

Add your desired Height and Width in dimens.xml like :

```
<dimen name="dimension10">10dp</dimen>
```

So you can use it in `R.dimen.dimension10`